# google play game service error -> 'Could not find class...GameHelper '

Tags: android, linker-errors, google-play-services

```
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
public class MyAppName extends Cocos2dxActivity implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener { 
....
.....

public static GameHelper gameHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameHelper  = new GameHelper(this);
  .....
```

error point: `gameHelper  = new GameHelper(this);`

error Message : `Could not find class 'com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper', referenced from method com.company.MyAppName.MyAppName.onCreate`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you referring a library project in your android project?

Answer (score 2):

1. On BaseGameUtils, go to Project Properties | Android. Verify that it's targeting a valid Android target that's present on your SDK (anything with API level >= 8 should work).
2. Also on the project properties screen for BaseGameUtils, check that the "Is Library" checkbox is checked.
3. Check that BaseGameUtil is referencing google-play-services_lib as a library. (Project Properties | Android | References).
4. Check that your project is referencing BaseGameUtil as a library (same).

Hope this helps!

Comment: i solved error.MyProject->Properties->Java Build Path ->Select All ->OK

Answer (score 0):

Did you define Basegameutils as a library project and include it as a reference ?

The doc that accompanies the sample is fairly good.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest BaseGameUtils project (I downloaded from google github on Aug 13, 2014), the source files are not under the src/ folder. so you will need to Properties->Java Build Path->Add folder and select the java folders.

If the project then compiles without error for the BaseGameUtils, great! I also encountered some other compilation errors and solved it by update the Google Play services to the latest version in SDK manager.

Hope it helps.