# Android class GameHelper could not be found

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, android-library, library-project

Evrytime I want to start my app I crashs with following exception:

```
06-28 23:15:08.474: E/dalvikvm(27890): Could not find class 'com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper', referenced from method com.example.sample.MainActivity.onCreate
06-28 23:15:08.704: E/AndroidRuntime(27890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 23:15:08.704: E/AndroidRuntime(27890): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper
```

I allready swaped the gen and src Folder (in Properties>Java Build Path> Order and Export). I've referenced BaseGameUtils as library-project in my project's properties and marked BaseGameUtils (which is referencing google-play-services_lib) and google-play-services_lib as library, too. Does anyone has a idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that 
EITHER BaseGameUtils may be targeting a version of the Android SDK that you have not downloaded
OR  you have a build path issue in your project check...Properties...Java Build Path ...Order and Export ...Select All ...OK

There are some other possible reasons given here:

[google play game service error -> 'Could not find class...GameHelper '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850668/google-play-game-service-error-could-not-find-class-gamehelper)

Good luck !

Comment: i see this answer as accepted but what was the exact solution? Was it something in build paths as mentioned? what was done to fix it?